# jQuery navigation header

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having a problem with the last exercise on the jQuery track of [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/web-beginner-en-R7w8I/0/1?curriculum_id=50a3fad8c7a770b5fd0007a1).

I am trying to recreate the navigation header as close as possible, but I can't find a way to let the selected div stay selected, when it's clicked.

Here is the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YAew4/8/).

And here is the original code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="show" contenteditable="true">Enter your text below:</div>
        <div id="back"></div>
        <div class="header">Files</div>
        <div class="header">index.html</div>
        <div class="header">style.css</div>
        <div class="header">script.js</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
#back {
    height: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
}

#show {
    background-color: rgb( 35, 44, 49 );
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    top: 58px;
    position: absolute;
}

.header {
    font-family: helvetica;
    float: left;
    background-color: #212121;
    color: rgb(105, 105, 105);
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#show").hide();
    $(".header").click(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate( {
            color: "white",
            backgroundColor: "rgb( 35, 44, 49 )"
        });
        $("#show").show();
    });

    $(".header").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
        $(this).stop().animate( {
            color: "white",
            backgroundColor: "rgb( 45, 60, 70 )"
        });
    });

    $(".header").mouseleave(function() {

            $(this).stop().animate( {
                color: "#696969",
                backgroundColor: "rgb( 33, 33, 33)"
            });
    });
});
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: what about adding an 'active' class?

Comment: Your mouseleave is resetting it back

Comment: Yes, the 'active' class seems to be the key.
I'm wondering what kind of other approaches are possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy solution to what you already have.

Add One line of CSS

```
.active { background-color: rgb( 35, 44, 49 ) !important; color: white !important; }
```

Then add one line and one method on ur script

```
$(".header").click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active').stop().animate( {
```

Comment: This solution works like a charm.
Thank you very much.
I can't vote up your answer because of my reputation, though.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/YAew4/12/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#show").hide();
    $(".header").click(function() {
        $('.header').removeClass('active');
        $(this).stop().animate( {
            color: "white",
            backgroundColor: "rgb( 35, 44, 49 )"
        });
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $("#show").show();
    });

    $(".header").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
        $(this).stop().animate( {
            color: "white",
            backgroundColor: "rgb( 45, 60, 70 )"
        });
    });

    $(".header").mouseleave(function() {

            $(this).stop().animate( {
                color: "#696969",
                backgroundColor: "rgb( 33, 33, 33 )"
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this...

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/YAew4/13/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#show").hide();
$(".header").click(function() {
    $('.header').removeClass('active');
    $(this).stop().animate( {
        color: "white",
        backgroundColor: "rgb( 35, 44, 49 )"
    });

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#show").show();
});

$(".header").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
    $(this).stop().animate( {
        color: "white",
        backgroundColor: "rgb( 45, 60, 70 )"
    });
});

$(".header").mouseleave(function() {

        $(this).stop().animate( {
            color: "#696969",
            backgroundColor: "rgb( 33, 33, 33 )"
        });
     });
 });
```

Then in your css add an active class...

```
.active {
color:white!important;
background:rgb( 45, 60, 70 )!important;
}
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/YAew4/13/)

Comment: Your code does seem to work, but the color of the selected <div> does not match the color of the #back <div>.
It should be like this:
`.active {
    color:white!important;
    background:rgb( 35, 44, 49 )!important;
}`
Thanks for your effort.